# beforeShowDay's title in bootstrap-datepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to insert some texts(`titleAttr` in this case) below each day in `datepicker`, I tried to achieve this via `beforeShowDay`. According to doc, the return value of the function regarding `beforeShowDay` is as follows,

> An object with the following properties:
>
> enabled: same as the Boolean value above
>
> classes: same as the String value above
>
> tooltip: a tooltip to apply to this date, via the title HTML attribute

So if I set `tooltip` to `titleAttr`, I will get multiple `a` tags with attributes `title` set to `titleAttr` in datepicker, so I can insert some texts after those `a` tags, but I didn't get any tag with attribute `title`, am I wrong?

```js
$datepicker = $('.input-group.date');
$datepicker.datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [true, "", "titleAttr"];
  }
});
```

```css
.datepicker td a[title]:after {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date pull-right" style="width: 150px;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your question [`beforeShowDay`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday) can return **An object with the following properties: ...** while in your case your `beforeShowDay` returns an `Array`.

If you change the return value to an `Object` with the mentioned proprieties you will have the following code:

```js
$datepicker = $('.input-group.date');
$datepicker.datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return {
      enabled: true,
      classes: "", 
      tooltip: "titleAttr"
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.datepicker td a[title]:after {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date pull-right" style="width: 150px;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note tha the HTML generated by the picker for a day is the following, so there is no `a` tag:

```
<td class="day" title="titleAttr">1</td>
```

Comment: Yes, I should return an `object` instead of an `array`. I cannot believe I've been looking for the answer for such a long time yet it's so simple. I must have confused `jquery-datepicker` with `bootstrap-datepicker`. Thanks!